# Inequlity $\frac{2}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}}\leq ax+by$ for $a+b=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

$\frac{2}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}}\leq ax+by$, where $a+b=1$ and $a,b,x,y>0$ real numbers.
Any hints?

part (a) was showing $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}\leq \sqrt{xy}\leq \frac{x+y}{2}$.

To give a you a taste here is one failed approach:

working backwards: $\frac{2}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}}\leq ax+by\Rightarrow$

$xy \leq \frac{(ax+by)}{2}(bx+ay)\Rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{2ab}\sqrt{axby} \sqrt{bx ay}\leq \frac{(ax+by)}{2}\frac{(bx+ay)}{2}$ but the LHS is greater than $\sqrt{axby} \sqrt{bx ay}$ so it is not reversible

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is wrong. That can be shown easily if we choose $a=b=x=y=\frac {1}{2}$ and observe that $1 \leq \frac {1}{2}$ which is ridiculous. 
 In fact, if we substitute $n=2$, $x_1 = \sqrt {ax}$, $x_2=\sqrt {by}$, $y_1=\sqrt {\frac {a}{x}}$ and $y_2=\sqrt {\frac {b}{y}}$ in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
$$ ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2})(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2}),$$
we have,
$$(ax+by)(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}) \geq (a+b)^2 =1,$$
i.e. $\frac {1}{\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}}\leq (ax+by)$ with equality holding iff $\frac{\sqrt{ax}}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}}=\frac{\sqrt{by}}{\sqrt{\frac{b}{y}}}$, i.e., $x=y$.

Comment: Thanks. Should have checked if it is correct after the 10th failed attempt.